# T-Sql MAX Datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, max

Hello and Thank you all for any assistance!
I am trying to retrieve the newest value based on the datetime field for the first 13 characters of entries in ValueCol1.

```
Value1Col1  DateTimeCol2
1234567891234   1/1/21 12:00 PM
1234567891234R1 1/1/21 12:01 PM
1234567891234A1 1/1/21 12:02 PM
1234567891235A2 1/1/21 12:00 PM
1234567891235R2 1/1/21 12:01 PM
1234567891235   1/1/21 12:02 PM
```

When using a Max date function:

```
Select max(datetimecol2), value1col1 from table1
group by valuecol1
```

I receive this output:

```
Value1  DateTime
1234567891234R1 1/1/21 12:01 PM
1234567891234A1 1/1/21 12:02 PM
1234567891235A2 1/1/21 12:00 PM
1234567891235R2 1/1/21 12:01 PM
```

I tried Max(value1) but sometimes A1 is newer than R1 and the results will return R1.
If more info is needed please let me know.  Thanks again for any help on this.

Comment: What are the data types of the two fields; if your field `DateTimeCol2` is not a date type it will not sort as expected.

Comment: Hi peter
value1 = char15
DateTimeCol1 = datetime
I need the most current of the two distinct left 13 characters in value1 column.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm totally lost.  The first 13 characters are `1234567891234` and `1234567891235`.  That seems to have nothing to do with the results.

Comment: Hi Gordon
From those two numbers I am needing the rows with the most recent date and time.  The time difference is only a minute or two from the original 13 characters, but over time the values characters can increase by the addition of a A# or R#.  Hope that helps.
It should result in two rows with the most recent datetime entry

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, not tested:

```
WITH MaxTime
AS
(
SELECT TOP 1
    datetimecol2
FROM table1
ORDER BY
    datetimecol2 DESC
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 AS T1
    JOIN
    MaxTime AS MT
   ON T1.datetimecol2 = MT.datetimecol2
```

That is, get the most recent value when sorted by the date and then join that to the original table to get all values with the maximum date

Answer (score 0):

Below query to get the max time of the table

```
select max(time) from table1
```

when you need other column value then you can use the below query :

```
select top 1 time,value1 from table1 order by time desc
```

To get all values max time

```
select max(time),value1 from table1 group by value1 having count(value1)>0
```

[image]

Comment: hi Rahul
The results needed should be 3 rows with the most current date, for values AA,BB,CC

Comment: @Chank I have updated the ans ,to get the data in group by, if this solves your problem then you can mark as accepted

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7160482/rahul-shukla
The query results return two rows each for1234567891234 and 1234567891235, both the R1 and A1. For some reason the timestamp is not being recognized as a max value.  How do i get the results for the newest timestamp of those two numbers?  Should be either A1 row or R1 row.

Comment: @Chank that is coming because you have same time for both so simple use the count query as per the updated query in answer. Due  to duplicate value it is giving duplicate time details

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from
 (select 
   ch13,Value1Col1,row_number() over (partition by ch13 order by DateTimeCol2 desc) rn   
   from (select Left(Value1Col1,13) as ch13,[Value1Col1],[DateTimeCol2]
   FROM [m1].[dbo].[StackO)t)Tg
   where Tg.rn=1
```

[image]

if you want exclude ch13:

[image]